# Pluralization of Latin origin words

Tags: nouns, latin, irregular-plurals

I heard that words borrowed from Latin take irregular plural form. (examples: datum/data, fungus/fungi, alga/algae)

But how can we tell that whether a word (such as 'bus', 'plum', or 'idea') has Latin origin? Is there obvious difference between Latin-origin words and others?

Comment: You need to consult a dictionary, just as you do if you want to know the plural of a word in e.g. German, or the past tense/participle form of a verb. There are rules of thumb which hopefully someone will elucidate, but there are always exceptions.

Comment: A dictionary will also tell you when two different plurals are common:  *index* -> *indexes, indices*.

Comment: The easiest way to tell is to get a cheap Latin dictionary and see how many words you recognize from English.

Comment: It's just experience. Because it's how language evolved, you can't expect there to be a rule for everything. Also, the examples you gave, 'bus', 'plum', and 'idea' all have Latin origin. It's different for different words.

Comment: I believe that this rule is also falling out of fashion.